# What is the C:\Documents~\[Account]\Application Data\Original\IETemply directory used for?

Tags: windows, internet

I want to retrieve all the pictures viewed on the web, and I was told I can find them in the C:\Documents~[Account]\Application Data\Original\IETemply directory.

I have a question. Does the directory mentioned above include all the pictures viewed on the web? What is the relationship between the directory and C:\Documents~[Account]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files?

Answer (score 1):

Bing only has one reference to "IETemply", and Google has two, both in Chinese.  Whatever that folder is, it is not a common folder used by IE.

As you note, the Temporary Internet Files directory is what IE uses to store, well, temporary internet files (pictures, cached webpages, etc).